# How to map column name in a table and corresponding names in a source file

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.5

I am inserting data's from excel sheet to a oracle database.Excel sheet is provided by the customers.I created a table in database.Structure and type is same between excel column name and table column name, but the column names differ.So in this situation how can i map column name in table and the column name in excel while inserting data ,do i need to create a xml file and map all the values or something different??.For insertion i have created my own ado.net dll.

Excel structure is  shown below

```
Firstname     lastname         Age     Salary

ricky         martin          34       45000
Jensen       thomas           37       55000
Kiran        di               32       34000
```

Table structure is shown below

```
F_name     l_name            _age      _salary
```

Code used to insert in to database is shown below

```
Arraylist ar = new Arraylist();
ar.Add(new FormField(colname, rowvalue, 2));
                dal.CreateInsertQuery(ar, "table_name", out sql, ref ErrorMessage);
                dal.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, ref ErrorMessage, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a `Dictionary<String, String>`, something like this:

```
Dictionary <String, String> fieldMap = new Dictionary<String, String>();
fieldMap.Add(oldName1, newName1);
fieldMap.Add(oldName2, newName2);
//etc.
```

Then you do something like this, when adding to the array, you can map the field during the add call.

```
ar.Add(new FormField(fieldMap[colname], rowvalue, 2));
```

where `fieldMap[colname]` returns the "new name" for `colname`.

Comment: this will do for a single sheet may be like an Automapper, but if customers are changing names time to time ,do we have a generic fix ?

Comment: If the column order stays consistent, then you  could map column number to name instead, as suggested by @腊鸭鸭.  You could change the `Dictionary` to a `<int,String>` to map column numbers to Oracle column names.